# Rearrange bytes to 24-bit pixel data in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am receiving raw Bayer pixel data from imager in an uint8_t buffer. Each pixel size is 3 bytes i.e. 01 23 45 from uint8_t buffer forms one pixel 012345. Is there an elegant way to convert/copy this data to an OpenCV MAT where each pixel represents 3 bytes of uint8_t buffer. The pixel size of OpenCV MAT would be 4 bytes since there is no 24-bit pixel format in OpenCV.

Comment: I presume this is C++ rather than Python?

Comment: Yes, I am using C++

Comment: "raw Bayer pixel data" at 24bits per pixel? That sounds quite unusual... what imager is that?

Comment: Anyway, make it a `CV_8UC3` mat, and use `mixChannels` to turn it into a `CV_8UC4` (taking care of endianness, you'll also need a dummy single channel of zeros) and then treat it as `CV_32SC1`. ... Perhaps allocate it as `CV_32SC1`, and create a temporary `CV_8UC4` header around the former's pixel buffer. Maybe even a call to `cvtColor` doing something like `BGR2BGRA` would be good enough. Not sure I'd call that elegant :D | Definitely try a simple loop as a baseline.

Comment: @DanMašek The `cvtColor(... BGR2BGRA)` sounds a great idea